# What is the trope known in Russian as "speaking name" called in English?

Tags: terminology, tropes

There's a trope known in Russian as "говорящее имя", i.e. "speaking name". The point of this trope is that a character's name (or surname) indicates its important, sometimes defining, feature. An example of it could be Pomona Sprout, a Herbology professor in *Harry Potter*. Another, even more important to the plot, is Remus Lupin, whose feature is that he's a werewolf.

Does this trope have a name in English?

Comment: @NorthLæraðr It seems on-topic to me, as a question about a piece of terminology used for a phenomenon in literature.

Comment: Cross-post of https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/263636/4376

Answer (score 2):

It's called [charactonym](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charactonym). From the link (Merriam-Webster dictionary):

> Definition of charactonym
>
> : a name especially for a fictional character (such as Mistress Quickly or Caspar Milquetoast) that suggests a distinctive trait of the character

Answer (score 1):

**Antonomasia**. From [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/antonomasia) (bold emphasis added):

> Antonomasia, a figure of speech in which some defining word or phrase is substituted for a person’s proper name (for example, “the Bard of Avon” for William Shakespeare). **In fiction, the practice of giving to a character a proper name that defines or suggests a leading quality of that character (such as Squire Allworthy, Doctor Sawbones) is also called antonomasia.** The word is from the Greek *antonomasía*, a derivative of *antonomázein*, “to call by a new name.”